# CustomAdapter for ExpandableListView using CompoundDrawable

Tags: java, android

be patient cause i'm just learning and i am a newbie.
I cant figure out how to set different `CompoundDrawable` for each Child in the following code.

Here are my `Activity` and `CustomAdapter`

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.DropBoxManager;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private ExpandableListView expListView;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);


    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}



/*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("NATIONS");



    // Adding child data
    List<String> NATIONS = new ArrayList<String>();
    NATIONS.add("AUSTRALIA");
    NATIONS.add("AUSTRIA");
    NATIONS.add("BELGIO");
    NATIONS.add("BRASILE");
    NATIONS.add("BULGARIA");
    NATIONS.add("CANADA");
    NATIONS.add("CILE");
    NATIONS.add("CINA");
    NATIONS.add("COLOMBIA");
    NATIONS.add("CUBA");
    NATIONS.add("ITALIA");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), NATIONS);// Header, Child data


    }

}
```

Now should i initialize an `Array of CompoundDrawable`? I did it but i cant get how to add it to the created `HashMap`

and the Adapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles


// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;

}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}


@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }


    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

// From this point i would like to set the Compound Drawable DIFFERENT for each childText.

    return convertView;
}



@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a List of String into the map you can add a List of ListDataChild where ListDataChild is a class that you must create and that looks like this:

```
public class ListDataChild {
    public String text;
    public Drawable drawable;

    public ListDataChild() {}

    public ListDataChild(String text, Drawable drawable) {
        this.text = text;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    } 
}
```

then in your 'prepareListData()' method

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<ListDataChild>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("NATIONS");

    // Adding child data
    Drawable[] drawables = ... //An array of preloaded Drawables
    List<ListDataChild> NATIONS = new ArrayList<ListDataChild>();
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("AUSTRALIA", drawables[0]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("AUSTRIA", drawables[1]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("BELGIO", drawables[2]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("BRASILE", drawables[3]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("BULGARIA", drawables[4]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("CANADA", drawables[5]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("CILE", drawables[6]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("CINA", drawables[7]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("COLOMBIA", drawables[8]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("CUBA", drawables[9]));
    NATIONS.add(new ListDataChild("ITALIA", drawables[10]));


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), NATIONS);// Header, Child data

}
```

then you change some lines of code in the Adapter class

```
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<ListDataChild>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                         HashMap<String, List<ListDataChild>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;

}
```

finally you can do something like this when you setup your child View

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent) {

    final ListDataChild child = (ListDataChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }


    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    //Set The TextView text
    txtListChild.setText(child.text);

    //Set left drawable
    txtListChild.setCompoundDrawables(child.drawable, null, null, null); 

    return convertView;
}
```

Anyway, I think saving Drawable into a Map is not the best choice (Because of memory usage). You can instead save the id of the drawable and then load the drawable when you need it. So the ListDataChild turns into this

```
public class ListDataChild {
    public String text;
    public int drawableId;

    public ListDataChild() {}

    public ListDataChild(String text, int drawableId) {
        this.text = text;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}
```

And when you need the Drawable you can load it:

```
ListDataChild child = ... //Your data child object
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, child.drawableId);
```

Comment: Prathamehd i followed all Your suggestions but i'm now at a dead point...sorry but as i told i'm really a newbie...

Comment: The point is that i do not understand how and where to add in the prepareList the "preloaded Array of drawables"... availble to some more help?